# VS Code - Python Module not loading, how to install or what is going on

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I moved to VS Code from PyCharm and trying to get my python program working. I have been trying to resolve this error. It works fine in the command prompt but in vs code something is not setup. I have added everything I can think of from the marketplace.

Can anyone help me get this thing up and going.

[image]

Comment: Double-check which python on your system is used to run the script. This can be seen on the lower left bar in VS code.

Comment: That was it, I had several and tested a few and found one that worked. Thanks